# TensorFlow costum loss: Implement Mix of L1 loss an SSIM loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, loss-function, ssim

I want to implement a similar loss function like in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.08861.pdf

They are combining here the l1 (Mean Average Error) and the MS-SSIM Loss like in following equation:
`L_Mix = α · L_MSSSIM + (1 − α) · GaussFilter· L_1` 
There is a caffe code available on GitHub: https://github.com/NVlabs/PL4NN/blob/master/src/loss.py

But I dont know how to use this in TF. Is there already a similar existing code for TF?
I started trying this:

```
def ms_ssim_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    ms_ssim = tf.image.ssim_multiscale(y_true, y_pred, 1.0)
    loss = 1-ms_ssim
    return loss

def mix_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    alpha = 0.84
    ms_ssim = ms_ssim_loss(y_true, y_pred)
    l1 = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(y_true, y_pred)
    gauss = gaussian(...)
    loss = ms_ssim * alpha + (1-alpha) * gauss * l1
    return loss
```

But don't know how to implement and use the gaussian filter here.

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was having the same issue as you, I wanted to use the ms-ssim +l1 loss using tensorflow , hopefully I think i managed to make it myself.

*note (the links to the paper you mention isnt the original paper for the ms-ssim + l1 loss)*
its is rather this one : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.08861.pdf

if we look on the cafe implementation we can read in comment for the ms-ssim + l1 function line 216

> "A loss layer that calculates alpha*(1-MSSSIM)+(1-alpha)*L1 loss. Assuming bottom[0] is output data and bottom[1] is label, meaning no back-propagation to bottom[1]."

so i implemented it like this :

```
def ms_ssim_l1(y_true, y_pred):
#loss layer that calculates alpha*(1-MSSSIM)+(1-alpha)*L1 loss
#https://github.com/NVlabs/PL4NN/blob/master/src/loss.py   
    max_picture_value = 65535.0
    alpha = 0.84

    mae_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs((y_true) - (y_pred)))
    
    if mae_loss <= 4000:
       msssim_loss = (1 - tf.image.ssim_multiscale(y_true, y_pred, max_picture_value))
    else:
       msssim_loss = (1 - tf.image.ssim(y_true, y_pred, max_picture_value))
    
    loss = (alpha * msssim_loss + (1-alpha) * mae_loss)
    
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

`max_picture_value` represent your picture range (I use 16bit picture)

this code use a mix of the ssim and ms-ssim function to avoid a bug caussing loss to go 'nan'

so you need to set a treshold using the `if mae_loss <= X` where **X** is is a value low enough for ms-ssim to be over 50% accurate
(from what I have read, it is related to ms-ssim not liking negative value)
i have also made some experiment, and it bug below that value

i hope this answer can help you or other like me that was looking for a way to use it in tensorflow :)